What does negative or minus symbol denote in a component datasheet?
I was going through the datasheet of IRF9540, a P-channel MOSFET.
The drain voltage and drain current is denoted with a minus or negative symbol, what does it mean, could someone please explain?


The current can still flow in both directions for N and P channel MOSFETs.

It denotes a negative number, the same as it does anywhere else.

\$V_{DS}\$ is this potential difference:
$$ V_{DS} = V_D - V_S $$
That is, source potential (second subscript) subtracted from drain potential (first subscript). The same convention is used for \$V_{GS}\$ and, for bipolar junction transistors \$V_{BE}\$ and \$V_{CE}\$:
$$ V_{GS} = V_G - V_S $$
$$ V_{BE} = V_B - V_E $$
$$ V_{CE} = V_C - V_E $$
All datasheets use this convention, at least I've never come across one that doesn't.
N-channel MOSFETs and NPN BJTs almost always have Drain(D) or collector (C) at the higher potential. No doubt you've seen them used like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note: there are occasions when NPN collector or NMOS drain are at a lower potential, but that is uncommon.
The source or emitter has the lower potential, and consequently values \$V_{DS}\$, \$V_{GS}\$, \$V_{BE}\$ and \$V_{CE}\$ are all positive.
Notably, the on/off state of these transistors is determined by \$V_{GS}\$ and \$V_{BE}\$, which in my examples here is provided by sources V1 and V2. For N-channel enhancement and NPN, a strongly positive value is required to switch them on.
Contrast this with the usual way we operate P-channel and PNP, where source and emitter have the higher potential:

simulate this circuit
The definitions don't change:
$$ V_{DS} = V_D - V_S $$
$$ V_{GS} = V_G - V_S $$
$$ V_{BE} = V_B - V_E $$
$$ V_{CE} = V_C - V_E $$
Since the gate/base now has a lower potential than the source/emitter, the values of \$V_{DS}\$, \$V_{GS}\$, \$V_{BE}\$ and \$V_{CE}\$ are now all negative. Also, I still set on/off state with V1 and V2, controlling \$V_{GS}\$ and \$V_{BE}\$, which must now be strongly negative to switch them on.
For this reason, datasheets for P-channel MOSFETS and PNP BJTs will quote these values as negative.

It's not just drain voltage Vd.
It reads Vds which means voltage of drain terminal in reference to source terminal.
As it's a P-channel FET, the normal use case is that source will be more positive than drain, which means Vds is negative on P-FETs and with the same convention, positive on N-FETs.
Also the current from drain is out from the P-FET, the current sign is negative. With same convention, N-FET current is into the drain and thus current sign is positive.
You will find the same convention in many places. For example supply current into an IC is positive, and ground current out is negative. For a logic IC like CMOS inverter, the the current being sourced from an output pin is negative, the current being sunk into the output pin is positive - depends on notation.

Thank you, I got clarity.

It's convention. The same thing applies to PNP and NPN transistors.
Vds is measured with a voltmeter, with (+) lead to drain and (-) lead to source. Ids is current into or out of the drain.
To understand this better, note that n-FET values for these (Vds, Ids) are positive. This means that when you measure Vds with a voltmeter, the (+) lead is on drain and (-) lead on source. A normally-biased nFET will have drain a higher voltage than source, so Vds will be positive. Likewise, current Ids flows into the drain, a more-negative potential, so is measured as a positive value.
p-FET values flip all the polarities, making Vds and Ids negative. Again, Vds is measured with (+) on drain and (-) on source, so for a normally-biased p-FET this will be negative. Likewise, Ids flows out of the drain from to a more-negative potential, so is regarded as negative.

Thank you, I got clarity.

Note also the use of plus-minus ±X which means the range of -X to +X.  It doesn't mean "more or less" in the sense of "approximately".
Thus in the following example, it means at 25°C the value will be in the range -0.1 μA (ie, out of the device) to +0.1 μA (ie into the device).

From Texas Instruments 74HCT374 datasheet
